# Instantiate Spacy object only once in apache mod_wsgi environment

Tags: apache, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi, spacy

**myapp.py**

```
----  import statements ---

parser = None

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/xxxxxx/yyy')

def markDealStatud():

    text = 'matthew honnibal created spacy library'

    parsedData = parser(text.decode("utf-8"))

    xxxxxxxxxxxxx

    xxxxxxxxxxxx


def initSpacy():

    global parser

    parser = English()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    initSpacy()

    app.run()​

if __name__ == 'myapp':

    initSpacy()
```

when i run this app in development mode, `__main__` will execute and it will instantiate spacy only once and i will use that.

For production we are using apache server mod_wsgi configuration. similarly i want to instantiate it once(myapp) and use the same obj. 
In my configuration it is instantiating for each request. Suggest some solution plz.

### Environment

- **Operating System:**  Linux
- **Python Version Used:**  2.7
- **Environment Information:** apache mod_wsgi deployment

Comment: Are you sure you aren't confusing things and what you are seeing is it being instantiated in different processes? If you are using embedded mode of mod_wsgi, then Apache is running with multiple processes. Switch to daemon mode instead. Output the process ID in your debug.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamDumpleton , We are not running in daemon mode. Now its working fine.